# How to check db connection through shell script?

Tags: database, shell, alert, jobs

I'm really new to scripting, I tired writing a script that checks the db connection exists or not. I'm planning to create a job to check the DB connection in particular intervals and send alert mail

Here is the code I tired writing, please correct me or suggest:

```
echo "exit" | sqlplus -L uid/pwd@dbname | grep Connected > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
   mailx -s "DB connection error" maild_id
else
   mailx -s "DB connection successful" maild_id
fi
```

Comment: What is your question? And what are the three backquote characters supposed to do at the end of your script?

Comment: it's a typo error.. I wanted to write a shell script that checks the db connection, success or not.

Comment: How to check db connection through shell script?

Comment: Don't put important information into comments, but into your question. In what respect does the code you were posting fail to do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Hi Jain, pls update the question to let us know what went wrong.  Did the sqlplus command behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks pretty good, but there is a logic flaw.  Like nearly all commands, `grep` will return an exit code of 0 when it is successful.  `grep "Connected"` will be successful when "Connected" is output by sqlplus.  Thus, your script should look like this:

```
echo "exit" | sqlplus -L uid/pwd@dbname | grep Connected > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
   mailx -s "DB connection successful" maild_id

else
   mailx -s "DB connection error" maild_id
fi
```

Here are some improvements that you can make:

1. sqlplus will exit when there is no more input on stdin.  Thus, the `echo "exit" is unnecessary.
2. You can avoid redirecting `grep` to `/dev/null` if you use the `-q` (quiet) parameter.  `grep` will just return 0 or 1 exit code indicating that it found the string.
3. You may find that sqlplus returns a 0 exit code when it connects successfully.  You probably don't have to look for the string "Connected".
4. You can execute the sqlplus command as the `if` condition.

Putting all of these together:

```
if
   >/dev/null sqlplus -L uid/pwd@dbname 
then 
   mailx -s "DB connection successful" maild_id
else 
   mailx -s "DB connection error" maild_id
fi
```

However, if I'm wrong about sqlplus exit codes, you can still write your script like this:

```
if
   echo "exit" | sqlplus -L uid/pwd@dbname | grep -q Connected 
then 
   mailx -s "DB connection successful" maild_id
else 
   mailx -s "DB connection error" maild_id
fi
```

You can also avoid the if ; then ; else ; fi construction altogether by using the `&&` conjuction.  `&&` is a logical AND operator - it will only evaluate the right expression if the left expression is true (it uses short circuited boolean logic).  Using this concept, and an assumption about sqlplus, we can re-write your code more compactly (but perhaps less legibly) as:

```
STATUS="error"
>/dev/null sqlplus  -L uid/pwd@dbname  && STATUS="successful"
mailx -s "DB connection $STATUS" maild_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the suggestions. But I have to connect the DB like this : 
./ssgodbc.linux64 -d "dsn" -u "username" -p 'pswd' -v
how can change this script? I tired replacing the sql part, but it didn't work

Comment: Try rewriting your question/post to share the errors that you are seeing.  This way, the whole community can learn from your situation.